# Why is this charge in the image not flowing into the earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

The question is in the image. I understand the solution provided in the image but it doesn't explain my question!

[image]

I think that charges move into earth because they are repelled among themselves if this is true then what's stopping them from doing so?

Comment: Aim of earthing is to make that surface zero potential.

Comment: As electric field is the driving force for charge, this field is produced by potential difference. Therefore charge flows till potential difference becomes zero.

Comment: See [Why are the charges pushed to the earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371865)